# What would be a good Flutter client for an Aqueduct server?

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

Writing my frontend app in Flutter/Dart, and my backend server using Aqueduct being written in Dart too, is there a tailored client that could e.g. reuse the models of Aqueduct?

Answer (score 1):

Short anwser:
The Aqueduct is dead. Long live the Aqueduct!

[it's been a long time since the last update.](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/919)

To be precise, Aqueduct is not alive, not dead.

Can I ask a reasonable question here?
What's the point of using a framework whose users have long worried about the lack of updates?

P.S.

Excuse me if my question seemed to you on the contrary, not very clever.

Comment: It does not answer the question but it is useful information that I would have liked to know earlier :) Now it's too late to change...

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, this happens very often in Dart. Even Google is abandoned not a few serious (and not) projects written in Dart. Support and development are expensive. Nobody wants to waste money.